# Возможно ли выделить циклы разной длительности из такого временного ряда

Tags: python, fft

есть ряды с ежегодными значениями, всего 30 элементов. разброс значений очень большой. [Таблица](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1keT0I_AkfZkZjWubgeZgcx0lv5dGZY0I/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105326785031219603112&rtpof=true&sd=true)

пример кривой для точки 10:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно ли в нем выделить циклы различной продолжительности или его длины недостаточно?

пробовал кодом разложить на тренд, сезонность и отклонения:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
line = pd.read_excel('acc_2.xlsx')
line = line.set_index('нет2006').T
x = 10 # номер точки
line[x].plot()

from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
decomposition = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(line[x], model = 'additive', period =int(len(line)/2)) 
# как я понял, period не может быть больше половины ряда 
decomposition.plot()
plt.show()

fxt = np.fft.fft(line[x])
plt.plot(fxt)
plt.show()
```

decomposition так разложил ряд на компоненты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

попытка разложения Фурье через fft на графике выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

возможно ли и как в данном случае использовать разложение Фурье для поиска циклов различной длительности?